# Tikz: question about arrow tips color and width of paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

1. Why 4-6, 4-7, 7-5 get these colorings? More precisely, what is the difference between [draw=green, fill=green] to [color=green]?
2. Why the 4-5 arc has a slightly bigger width that 7-6? You can see a faint black outerline in the 4-5 arc.

This is a minimal example with my questions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, trees, mindmap, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{every node/.style={minimum size=5pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, node distance=25pt}}
\tikzset{black circle/.style={every node, shape=circle, draw=black, fill=black, text=white}}
\tikzset{thick edge/.style={-, black, fill=none, thick, text=black}}
\tikzset{thick arc/.style={->, black, fill=none, thick, >=stealth, text=black}}

\node[black circle] (4) {4};
\node[black circle, below=of 4] (5) {5};
\node[black circle, right=of 5] (6) {6};
\node[black circle, above=of 6] (7) {7};

\draw[thick arc] (4) -- (5);
\draw[thick arc, green] (7) -- (6);
\draw[thick arc, color=green] (4) -- (6);

\draw[thick arc, draw=green] (7) -- (5);

\draw[thick arc, draw=green, fill=green] (4) -- (7);

\draw[thick arc, green] (4) -- (5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

1. There are three different options for setting colours of specific elements: `draw`, `fill`, and `text`. The colour specified using `draw` applies to outlines, `fill` applies to areas (and filled arrow tips, like `stealth` and `latex`, but unlike the default), `text` applies to the text in nodes. `color` is a shorthand for setting all three of these simultaneously. Just specifying a colour on its own is a shorthand for the shorthand: It also applies to `draw`, `fill` and `text`.

   `green` and `color=green` are equivalent, and since you're not using text in your example, `fill=green, draw=green` is also equivalent here.
2. The faint black outline comes from the fact that you're drawing the arrow from `4` to `5` twice: First in black, then again in green. The faint outline is an artefact of the anti-aliasing of the renderer (see the discussion at [TikZ borders showing through when they shouldn't (overlapping circles)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49614/86)).