# How to draw a black arrow?

Tags: beamer

How to draw a black arrow , please ?

I've tried using this `$\Rightarrow$`, but it wouldn't work properly.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of arrow do you need? Extensible, curved, straight?

Comment: An overview of some of the arrows available appears here: http://www.sascha-frank.com/Arrow/latex-arrows.html

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, This [one](https://www.google.tn/search?q=arrow&client=firefox-a&hs=Q3g&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&channel=fflb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=wJRyU9asEaXW0QXt8ICICw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1600&bih=789#channel=fflb&q=arrow+black&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=VNTaA03wSCSKAM%253A%3BlCNWSY36oubsdM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fupload.wikimedia.org%252Fwikipedia%252Fcommons%252F9%252F9c%252FBlack_Arrow_Up.svg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fcommons.wikimedia.org%252Fwiki%252FFile%253ABlack_Arrow_Up.svg%3B746%3B746) directed to the right.

Comment: Or [this](https://www.google.tn/search?q=arrow&client=firefox-a&hs=Q3g&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&channel=fflb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=wJRyU9asEaXW0QXt8ICICw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1600&bih=789#channel=fflb&q=arrow+black&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=sQssYuXwThA3iM%253A%3Bn-OA9e11bGmfCM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.clker.com%252Fcliparts%252F3%252F9%252F0%252F3%252FA%252Fs%252Fblack-arrow.svg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.clker.com%252Fclipart-black-arrow-3.html%3B686%3B336).

Comment: @Djouma just the arrow tip? (Your first link opens an arrow tip pointing upwards).

Comment: Relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107095/changing-line-thickness-of-arrow

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, you can just draw the second if u want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Three possibilities (there are many more; search the pgf manual for the `arrows.meta` library); adjust the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tikz\draw[->,line width=8pt] (0,0) -- (3,0);

\tikz\draw[-Latex,line width=8pt] (0,0) -- (3,0);

\tikz\node at (2,0) [fill=black,shape=single arrow,text width=2cm,text height=2.5ex] {};
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how would i place any of these arrows on top of other things in the background without disturbing them?  using your code directly shifts things under the arrow out of the way.