# Plot Eclipse in Latex

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to plot the picture below in latex and I am not good with graphs.[image]

Comment: Example with intersection: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/ or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228605/124842 with ellipse

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thank you for the links, could you please write the code. I have hard time make it looks like the picture with half dots lines and the labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a try, but i'm also no expert. Trying is learning. It would be better to detect the intersection, but I don't know how...

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%Ref: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228605/124842
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\firstellipse{(-5,0) ellipse (8 and 4.5)}
    \def\secondellipse{(-6,-1) ellipse (3 and 2.5)}
    \def\thirdellipse{(-4,-0.5) ellipse (3 and 2.5)}

    % colour ellipses
    \fill[white] \firstellipse ;
    \fill[white] \secondellipse;
    \fill[gray] \thirdellipse;

    \draw[gray] \thirdellipse;

    % colour intersection
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \secondellipse;
        \fill[white] \thirdellipse \firstellipse;
    \end{scope}

   \draw \firstellipse \secondellipse;
   \draw[gray,dashed]  \thirdellipse;

   \node[draw, fill=white] at (-11.5, 2.8)   (b) {$SS_{TOT}$};
   \node at (-6.5, -1.5)   (b) {$SSR(X_2,X_3)$};


   %Ref:http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107101/124842
   \draw[black,solid,line width=1mm,fill=black,preaction={-triangle 90,thin,draw,shorten >=-1mm}] (1.5, 3.5) node[above]{$SSR(X_2,X_3)$} -- (-2,1) node[above, scale = 2.3] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```