# Strange line width problem with tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees, tikz-qtree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TikZ borders showing through when they shouldn’t (overlapping circles)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49614/tikz-borders-showing-through-when-they-shouldnt-overlapping-circles)

I have a strange problem with using tikz-qtree where the thickness of the lines are a bit odd. When I say odd I mean that when you zoom in it looks fine, and when you zoom out some of the lines appear thicker. I think its due to lines overlapping. Do you have any ideas?

Here's an example that shows the behaviour I'm talking about:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering  
            \begin {tikzpicture}[sibling distance=20pt]
            \tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
               {draw,
                edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
                            -- +(0,-8pt)
                            -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}  

            \Tree [.{\bf Sibiu}  [.{Oradea (380)} ] [.{Arad (366)} ]      [.{Rimnicu V. (192) } ]   [.{\bf Fagaras (176)} {Bucharest (0)}  ] ]
            %\Tree [.A [.B D E ] [.C F G ] ]
            \end {tikzpicture}
            \caption{Evaluating the adjacent nodes to Fagaras in a greedy search.}
            \label {fig:GreedySecond}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Compile it to a pdf and try zooming in and out (look towards the center), it's subtle but noticeable enough that I don't want it in my thesis. I'm pretty sure it happens when I run Evince on Linux and when I run Foxit on Windows. If nobody can tell what I mean I'll post some screenshots but I'm sure some people here are as pedantic as I am about presentation.

Comment: This has been asked a few times and related to the upsampling/downsampling of the pixels. It doesn't appear if you print it. Having said that the problem comes from the fact that the branches are drawn twice so you get overprinted line segments. If it is really bothering you, draw the horizontal part externally.

Comment: Is it a TeX issue or a PDF viewer issue?

Comment: @percusse How about a short answer (or a link to a possible duplicate)?

Comment: @lockstep Done. And also see this answer for an AcroRead specific potential remedy. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52821/3235