TikZ: Glow for rectangular node
I would like to use a glow effect for colored nodes holding some text. Unfortunately, I can only find the key circular glow, see the example below.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-2, -3) rectangle (2,3);
\node[circular glow={fill=green}, rectangle, text width=2.5cm, align=justify] {Given the rectangular text area, rectangular glow would be desirable to also cover the corners.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Is there a way to get a rectangular colored area with similar glow as the circular area above has, i.e., something like "rectangular glow"?

You could play with \shade "dividing" your shading area into four parts, taking advantage of local bounding box option to avoid putting explicit coordinates.
I also created a \pic with two arguments: the first is the name of the rectangular area you would like to shade, in my example mybox; the second is the color you would like to use, in my example green.
Of course, you could add other parameters, for example the other color for shading, in my examples "white" is fix.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings, backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    pics/myshade/.style 2 args={
        code = {%
          \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \shade[upper left=white, upper right=#2,
            lower left=white,lower right=white]
            (#1.south west) rectangle (#1.center);
            \shade[upper left=#2, upper right=white,
            lower left=white,lower right=white]
            (#1.south) rectangle (#1.east);
            \shade[upper left=white, upper right=white,
            lower left=#2,lower right=white]
            (#1.center) rectangle (#1.north east);
            \shade[upper left=white, upper right=white,
            lower left=white,lower right=#2]
            (#1.west) rectangle (#1.north);
          \end{scope}
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[local bounding box=mybox]
        \clip (-2, -3) rectangle (2,3);
        \pic {myshade={mybox}{green}};
        \node[rectangle, text width=2.5cm, align=justify] 
        {Given the rectangular text area, rectangular glow would be desirable to also cover the corners.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The option on background layer is not needed in your case, but I added it to make the pic myshade more general (avoiding it could overwrite the area, see the following example, without on background layer the text of mynode would be hidden under the shading).
Just to show how you can use the pic myshade for shading any rectangular areas. The bounding box is shaded in red, the node is shaded in cyan:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings, backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    pics/myshade/.style 2 args={
        code = {%
          \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \shade[upper left=white, upper right=#2,
            lower left=white,lower right=white]
            (#1.south west) rectangle (#1.center);
            \shade[upper left=#2, upper right=white,
            lower left=white,lower right=white]
            (#1.south) rectangle (#1.east);
            \shade[upper left=white, upper right=white,
            lower left=#2,lower right=white]
            (#1.center) rectangle (#1.north east);
            \shade[upper left=white, upper right=white,
            lower left=white,lower right=#2]
            (#1.west) rectangle (#1.north);
          \end{scope}
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[local bounding box=mybox]
        \clip (-2, -3) rectangle (2,3);
        \pic {myshade={mybox}{red}};
        \node[rectangle, text width=2.5cm, align=justify] (mynode)
        {Given the rectangular text area, rectangular glow would be desirable to also cover the corners.};
        \pic {myshade={mynode}{cyan}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thanks! I modified your solution to shade triangles, e.g.,
\shade[top color=white, bottom color=#2, middle color=#2] (#1.north west) -- (#1.north east) -- (#1.center) -- cycle;
That gives me artefacts on the diagonals. There are no artefacts visible where you patch your rectangles; can you tell why I get them?

@user279611 I afraid it's a matter of PDF render, I see the lines in Overleaf but I don't see them when I open the document with Acrobat. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49614/tikz-borders-showing-through-when-they-shouldnt-overlapping-circles

Thanks for the reference, good to know (I was using evince here...)!

@user279611 You're welcome! And thank you for accepting my answer.

Not really. Let's have a look at the manual:

So what you can do is trying to pretend some kind of glow by adding a general shadow. If you select scale and fill color carefully, it comes quite close.
You can also add a fading, see its library, but it doesn't provide a scaled fading, as you want (only N, W, S, E, circular(s)).
Opinion: In terms of legibility, the drop shadow might not be that bad ... if you need such effects, BTW. Remember, TeX/LaTeX origin from typesetting professional documents, like books. To a large extent it still resists the MS-Office-path ... which I like. More often than not, this more restrictive approach helps communicating visual messages differently, if not better.
I replaced your clip by some large enough border.

\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
%   \clip (-2, -3) rectangle (2,3);
    \node[
        circular glow={fill=green}, 
        rectangle,
        text width=2.5cm, 
        align=justify
    ] at (0,0)
    {Given the rectangular text area, rectangular glow would be desirable to also cover the corners.};
    
    \node[
        general shadow={fill=green!45,shadow scale=1.05}, 
%       drop shadow, fill=green,
        rectangle, fill=green,
        text width=2.5cm, 
        align=justify
    ] at (5,0)
    {Given the rectangular text area, rectangular glow would be desirable to also cover the corners.};
    
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

